# How to subset a series of dates

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a series of dates in a data frame. I would like to subset different segments of the data.

For instance using the built in dataset

```
data("JohnsonJohnson")
```

How would I subset values between 1965-1975? Then 1975-1985? For example.

Note: the dataset I ultimately want to use this on is formatted as a data frame rather than a time series, if that makes a difference.

**Edit:**

Here is a snip it of my data frame:

```
structure(list(date = c("2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", 
"2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", 
"2016-03-07", "2016-03-07"), hour = c("00", "01", "02", "03", 
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09"), temp1mK = c(276.50325, 276.8655, 
277.5455, 277.25875, 277.6625, 277.28475, 277.0955, 277.6815, 
278.2325, 279.9765), index = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N-S", "N-S", "E-W", "E-W", "OS"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", "hour", "temp1mK", 
"index"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please include `head` of the data frame you ultimately want to subset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To subset a data frame with a column showing dates based on year, it would be great if you can convert the date column to the `Date` class in `R` because it is easier to work with. The following example shows how to use functions from the `lubridate` package to work on the `Date` class.

First of all, your example dataset contains records only from the year `2016` based on the `date` column. I decided to replace the `date` column with a sequence of May 1st starting `2001` to `2010`.

#### Data Preparation

```
# Example data frame
dt <- structure(list(date = c("2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", 
                              "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07", 
                              "2016-03-07", "2016-03-07"), hour = c("00", "01", "02", "03", 
                                                                    "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09"), temp1mK = c(276.50325, 276.8655, 
                                                                                                                     277.5455, 277.25875, 277.6625, 277.28475, 277.0955, 277.6815, 
                                                                                                                     278.2325, 279.9765), index = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N-S", "N-S", "E-W", "E-W", "OS"
                                                                                                                                                              ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", "hour", "temp1mK", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                "index"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


# Update the date column
dt$date <- paste(2001:2010, "05", "01", sep = "-")
```

The example dataset now looks like this.

```
         date hour  temp1mK index
1  2001-05-01   00 276.5032   N-S
2  2002-05-01   01 276.8655   N-S
3  2003-05-01   02 277.5455   N-S
4  2004-05-01   03 277.2588   N-S
5  2005-05-01   04 277.6625   N-S
6  2006-05-01   05 277.2847   N-S
7  2007-05-01   06 277.0955   N-S
8  2008-05-01   07 277.6815   N-S
9  2009-05-01   08 278.2325   N-S
10 2010-05-01   09 279.9765   N-S
```

Notice that the `date` column is in `character` class. I am going to convert this column to `Date` class.

#### Convert to Date class

Now I loaded the `lubridate` package.

```
# Load packages
library(lubridate)
```

The format of the `date` column is `year-month-day`, so we can use the `ymd` function.

```
# Convert the date column to Date class
dt$date <- ymd(dt$date)
```

If your dataset has a different date format, you can use other functions like `dmy` or `mdy`.

The `date` column is now in `Date` class. We can type `class(dt$date)` to confirm.

Finally, there are two options to subset the data by the `date` column.

#### Option 1: Subset by a Specific Date

You can set the beginning and ending date to subset the data. Remember to convert the beginging and ending date to `Date` class as well.

```
dt_2001_2005 <- subset(dt, date >= ymd("2001-01-01") & date <= ymd("2005-12-31"))
dt_2006_2010 <- subset(dt, date >= ymd("2006-01-01") & date <= ymd("2010-12-31"))
```

#### Option 2: Subset by Year

We can also use the `year` function from the `lubridate` package to convert the `Date` class to numeric year number.

```
dt_2001_2005 <- subset(dt, year(date) >= 2001 & year(date) <= 2005)
dt_2006_2010 <- subset(dt, year(date) >= 2006 & year(date) <= 2010)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tempdata <- structure(list(date = c("1990-03-07", "1985-03-07", "2012-03-07", 
                        "2012-03-07", "1990-03-07", "1985-03-07", "1990-03-07", "2013-03-07", 
                        "2016-03-07", "2013-03-07"), hour = c("00", "01", "02", "03", 
                                                              "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09"), temp1mK = c(276.50325, 276.8655, 
                                                                                                               277.5455, 277.25875, 277.6625, 277.28475, 277.0955, 277.6815, 
                                                                                                               278.2325, 279.9765), index = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N-S", "N-S", "E-W", "E-W", "OS"
                                                                                                                                                        ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", "hour", "temp1mK", 
                                                                                                                                                                                          "index"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
year_subset_1980_2000 <- subset(tempdata, date <= "2000" & date > "1980" )
year_subset_2000_2015 <- subset(tempdata, date <= "2015" & date > "2000" )
```

Comment: Please update your original answer instead of having multiple answer posts (assuming the second one is the updated version)